# Как задать стиль тем сообщениям, которые написал $_SESSION['user_id']?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Вытаскиваю из базы все сообщения 
PHP:

```
function getMessages($link){
    $query = 'select c.*, u.username from users u inner JOIN chat c ON (u.id = c.user_id)';// order by c.id DESC LIMIT 0,30';
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $ar = array();
    for ($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $row['isMine'] = ($row['user_id']==$_SESSION['user_id']) ? 1 : 0;
        $ar[] = $row;
    }
    return $ar; 
}
```

Вывод все сообщений через Ajax

```
function getMessages(){
    data = {action:'listMessages'};
    $.post('core.php',data,function (response){
        obj = JSON.parse(response);
        $('#messages').html('');
        $.each(obj, function (key,value){
                message = '<div class="block_msg_usr">' + value['username']+ '</div>';
                message += '<div class="block_msg">' + value['message']+ '</div>';
                message += '<div class="block_msg_dt">' + value['created'] + '<div>';
                message += '<br>';
            $('#messages').append(message);
        });

    });
}
```

Вопрос: Как задать стиль тем сообщениям, которые написал $_SESSION['user_id']?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript код:

```
function getMessages(){
    data = {action:'listMessages'};
    $.post('core.php',data,function (response){
        obj = JSON.parse(response);
        $('#messages').html('');
        $.each(obj, function (key,value){
            message  = (value.isMine === 1) ? '<div class="block_msg_usr mine">' + value['username']+ '</div>' : '<div class="block_msg_usr">' + value['username']+ '</div>';
            message += (value.isMine === 1) ? '<div class="block_msg mine">' + value['message']+ '</div>' : '<div class="block_msg">' + value['message']+ '</div>';
            message += (value.isMine === 1) ? '<div class="block_msg_dt mine">' + value['created'] + '<div>' : '<div class="block_msg_dt">' + value['created'] + '<div>';
            message += '<br>';
            $('#messages').append(message);
        });

    });
}
```

CSS стили:

```
.block_msg_usr {
    background: #000000; /* Чужое сообщение */
}

.block_msg_usr.mine {
    background: #FFFFFF; /* Мое сообщение */
}
```

**P.S.** По тому же принципу и `.block_msg` и `.block_msg_dt`.

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек ))